# window.showModalDialog is Appearing twice in IE8

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am doing Dialog box development in CRM 4.0. Opening the dialog box through this line:-

JavaScript="window.showModalDialog('http://localhost/CinmarPages/BatchPurchaseOrderChange.aspx', window, 'dialogHeight: 400px; dialogWidth: 600px;help:0;status:0;scroll:0'); crmGrid.Refresh();"

On the Ok button of this dialog box the code written is something Save operation + alert('xxxx') + window.close(); and on the cancel button window.close();.

The issue which I am facing is when I choose OK or cancel button, the current ModalDialog behaviour is as expected, but the same URL of ModalDialog open again in full fledge IE browser. This is happening only in production when I am browsing the production IE browser instance, while if I access the production CRM from any other machine, the workflow and everything is fine means, its not opening again.

I feel there is some setting issue in the production IE browser. Since, many of CRM user accessing production machine through terminal services, so I need this functionality to work on production too. Windows server 2003 R2 x64 (with SP2) with IE8 is installed on production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `<base target="_self"/>` under the `<head>` tag.

From: [here](http://community.dynamics.com/blogs/hardworkdays/archive/2009/10/20/showmodaldialog-and-postbacks-in-custom-aspx-pages-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0.aspx), and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/datagridgirl/archive/2005/08/11/422309.aspx).